# closing modal opened with Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync displayInIframe:true crashes owa.clientnext.extensibility.js

Tags: office365, outlook-addin, office-js, office365-apps, outlook-web-addins

In the outlook365 web app when I try to close a modal opened with Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync (by clicking on the x) the modal does not actually close (the contents simply turn blank) and the following trace is shown in the console

[stacktrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYYf4.png)

Wondering if this is an issue inside the office.js library, as I am simply trying to close a modal with the x as supplied by default in Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync

The code used to invoke the dialog is the following:

```
        window.Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync('https://localhost:3000/test', { displayInIframe: true, height: 50, width: 50 }, (asyncResult) => {
        console.log('test!');
    });
```

and here is a screen capture of the issue

https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/bt-debugging/office_modal_screencapture.gif

Comment: Can you provide more details to your repro? 

What is your call to displayDialog look like? 
What browser are you using? (product and version) 
Do you know the exchange server version that you are on? 

On Chrome I tried: 
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync("someurl", {displayInIframe:true, height:50, width:50});

(along with displayInIFrame = false) 

And this didn't repro for me.

Comment: @OutlookWebAddinsTeam yes, absolutely, browser is Chrome on OSX Version 57.0.2987.133

Comment: @OutlookWebAddinsTeam I've added some more information to the initial post as well, a screen capture and a little code snippet showing how the dialog is being invoked.

Comment: This issue has been resolved and should be rolled out to production soon.